# Is there anyway to control CSS positioning in adobe fireworks?

Tags: html, css, adobe, fireworks

When i work on fireworks and export files into CSS and html , the DIVs are all absolute to top , is there anyway to make Divs relative to parent within Adobe fireworks?
Is there any plugin can solve this?

Comment: The best I can suggest is don't use the export of Fireworks ... That throw all kind of useless code and use the most ugly markup to acomplish the WYSIWYG

Comment: You want to say that fireworks export is useless despite its time saving making all the Divs i need?

Comment: div's aren't difficult to initialise

Comment: @ahmedamro Yes. It's bloated.

Comment: @Danko what do you suggest ?

Comment: As a suggestion start learn the basic of html and CSS to make layouts, In my case I'm a web designer and even if I'm no t in charge to do the markup and front-end code I really like to know what is involved on each step of the process.

Comment: @Danko What do you think of the answer below from Sleek Geek

Comment: @Danko my brother is already very awesome in CSS and we found that fireworks is just faster in making the Divs.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong mate the true is I learn fireworks a few years ago and on that time the program use tables and make very ugly things with nested elements. Then I stop to use it to generate the code and learn to do it myself, I'm still use that to present the look & feel and make some slices but prefer to do the code myself then I can handle it more easy if want changes or do things without use fireworks first.

Comment: @Danko the problem that all CSS looks different from what i design on photoshop. but you are right even my brother opinion is like you about fireworks.

Comment: @ahmedamro you are right there is a tiny line between the design and the exact posibilities of the CSS code. But today are great posibilities to start and learn to merge the two parts perfect way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you wrap everything after from the start body tag in  one container with a position property value of relative and a defined width. That will help you hold everything in you defined position except when you use negative values for **left, right, top or bottom** for the fireworks elements.

**CSS example**

```
 #main-container {
       position: relative;
       width: 960px; /* Adjust as needed */
       height: auto;
    }
```

**HTML example**

```
<div id="main-container">

 Put your fireworks stuff here

</div><!-- End Main Container -->
```